# Shortening my code with input boxes

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<form>
    <span style="float: left; width: 80px;">First name:</span> <input type="text"      name="firstname"><br />
    <span style="float: left; width: 80px;">Last name:</span> <input type="text" name="lastname"><br />
    <span style="float: left; width: 80px;">Mail:</span> <input type="text" name="mail"><br />
    <span style="float: left; width: 80px;">Password:</span></span> <input type="password" name="pwd">
</form>
```

I don't know why `class` is not working. I tried making a `.floatext` class in my CSS file instead of repeatedly typing `style=""`.

```
.floatext {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
}
```

Then I tried to do this:

```
<form>
    <span class="floatext">First name:</span> <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
    <span sclass="floatext">Last name:</span> <input type="text" name="lastname"><br />
    <span class="floatext">Mail:</span> <input type="text" name="mail"><br />
    <span class="floatext">Password:</span></span> <input type="password" name="pwd">
</form>
```

But it doesn't work. Only the code using `style` worked.... Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see is that one of your `class` attributes is misspelled as `sclass`. Otherwise it seems to work for me (tested using [this little tool](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <span class="floatext">First name:</span> <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
        <span class="floatext">Last name:</span> <input type="text" name="lastname"><br />
        <span class="floatext">Mail:</span> <input type="text" name="mail"><br />
        <span class="floatext">Password:</span></span> <input type="password" name="pwd">
    </form>
```

remove the s infront of the class in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Click this link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7K5va/) to navigate to the fiddle. If you modify the width inside the style inside the head and hit run on the top left then you'll see the new output reflected on the bottom right.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
.floatext {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
}</style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <span class="floatext">First name:</span> <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
        <span class="floatext">Last name:</span> <input type="text" name="lastname"><br />
        <span class="floatext">Mail:</span> <input type="text" name="mail"><br />
        <span class="floatext">Password:</span></span> <input type="password" name="pwd">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have a file separately for your CSS then inside the " " you would have something like this below:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Style/myFile.css" />
</head>
```